# Not able to change sshd_config on Google Coral dev board

Tags: ssh, google-coral, mendel-os

So I got my dev board earlier this week. I was trying to get started with and have been able to reflash it and my Chromebook is able to see the device when I do a "mdt devices" but when I do an "mdt shell", I get an error. I tried ssh directly and the verbose messages are shown below. My Chromebook was not able to see the devices using the USB-C data connection but then I was able to connect to it via the USB-serial connection and use the nmtui to connect the dev board to WiFi (same network to which the Chromebook is connected). The problem, from what I can read on Stackoverflow and other places is to do with sshd config on the board, needs to either have PAM disabled or password authentication enabled. I was trying to do that but then I see that I (the user mendel) cannot edit the /etc/ssh/sshd_config file because mendel is not in sudoers, which is weird because there is a 99-mendel-sudo in runonce.d which does precisely that (please see https://coral.googlesource.com/mendel-minimal/+/refs/heads/master/etc/runonce.d/99-mendel-sudo, I verified this file exists on my dev board).

So, does anyone know a workaround for this issue (root password?). I read several people talking about ssh issues and all solutions involve editing sshd_config which makes sense, of course. Only thing is that none of those pages (on Medium, Stackoverflow, GitHub) ever mention that something special is needed to first add mendel to /etc/sudoers. Seems like either I am missing something or something is broken regarding adding mendel to sudoers.

Here is my mendel Linux version:

```
mendel@tuned-eft:~$ uname -a
Linux tuned-eft 4.14.98-imx #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri Jul 17 01:15:45 UTC 2020 aarch64 GNU/Linux
mendel@tuned-eft:~$ cat /etc/mendel_version
5.0
mendel@tuned-eft:~$
```

Here are the ssh messages from my Chromebook:

```
amiarora@penguin:~$ ssh -v amiarora@tuned-eft c i eth i

OpenSSH_7.9p1 Debian-10+deb10u2, OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to tuned-eft [10.55.1.187] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/amiarora/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/amiarora/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/amiarora/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/amiarora/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/amiarora/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/amiarora/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/amiarora/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/amiarora/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/amiarora/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /home/amiarora/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.9p1 Debian-10+deb10u2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.9p1 Debian-10+deb10u2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.9p1 Debian-10+deb10u2 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to tuned-eft:22 as 'amiarora'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
Connection closed by 10.55.1.187 port 22
amiarora@penguin:~$
```

Output of the groups command on the dev board.

```
mendel@tuned-eft:~$ groups
mendel adm sudo audio video plugdev staff games users netdev input render i2c systemd-journal bluetooth apex
mendel@tuned-eft:~$ sudo sudosh
>>> /etc/sudoers: syntax error near line 28 <<<
sudo: parse error in /etc/sudoers near line 28
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
mendel@tuned-eft:~$
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing that seems really odd to me is that your `mendel` user doesn't have sudoer access but it really should be by default. Without that, there isn't much options to change the `sshd_config` or the `sudoers` file. My best suggestion is to go ahead and reflash the board using these instructions:
https://coral.ai/docs/dev-board/reflash/#flash-the-board

Instead of `mdt reboot-bootloader`, you may have to just reboot the board manually and type anything within the first 3 seconds of it booting up to go into u-boot mode and type this in the u-boot prompt to get into fastboot mode:

```
fastboot 0
```

For reference, this is what my `/etc/sudoer` looks like:

```
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        mail_badpass
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
mendel ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Comment: Reflashing the board solved the problem. I do not believe that I did anything different from what I did earlier, but it did indeed solve the problem. Interestingly, while "mdt shell" worked but when I was connected over the serial port (after re-flashing the board) I still could not edit /etc/ssh/sshd_config (it still said permission denied) but when I did mdt shell over the network and that worked and now from the shell when I tried to edit /etc/ssh/sshd_config it allowed me! So anyhow, works now. Thanks fro your help.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend still using key-pair authentication, but use the USB-serial connection to set that up.

- Generate a key pair (e.g. ssh-keygen)
- On your Chromebook, run mdt setkey [private key]
- Copy the public key to your clipboard
- On your device (via USB serial), edit ~/.ssh/authorized_keys (you likely will
  need to make both .ssh and authorized keys). Copy in your public key.
- MDT should now work as expected (I like to use mdt set
  preferred-device [ip addr] so I don't need to add the ip address to
  commands).

As for the sudoers question, it's surprising to hear that mendel doesn't have sudo access. Checking on my board:

```
mendel@elusive-dog:~$ groups
mendel adm sudo audio video plugdev staff games users netdev input render i2c systemd-journal bluetooth apex
```

Can you verify?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried the steps you mentioned, still the exact same results as I provided in the logs above.

Comment: I updated the original question to include the output of the groups command.